# Java- Synchronization/Locking across multiple files

Tags: java, multithreading, file

In my program, I will be storing each "block" of data in a separate file. Multiple threads will both read from and write to various files, and I want to avoid possible problems from not synchronizing this properly. Essentially, I want a setup where each file behaves as if it has its own `ReadWriteLock` (Two threads can write to two different files concurrently, but not to the same file). I could do just this (And do some optimizations where `ReadWriteLock`s are only instantiated when they are needed and destroyed when not), but I'm not sure that this is the "proper" thing to do. Is there a better way to do this?

I've read that using a `FileLock` would *not* be the right thing to do in this situation, because it only matters between different processes, and would not do anything in this case because all of my threads are in the same process.

To summarize: What I want to avoid is having one thread reading from one file locking out every other thread from doing anything with the many other files.

Comment: why not create a singleton class that handles this for you.

Comment: The solution that I described would be a Singleton, which would grant read and write locks for each file to the various threads as they request the locks. What I want to avoid is having one thread reading from one file locking out every other thread from doing anything with the many other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example singleton class that provides most of the functionality I think you are describing.  It maintains a map of file names to ReadWriteLocks and allows callers to acquire/release a lock based on a file name and a READ/WRITE access type.  The class instantiates locks on first use, and hides lock objects from the caller, which should help you to safely clean up locks that are not in use.

```
public enum LockRegistry {

// make our class a singleton
INSTANCE;

// map of file names to locks - You may want to change the keys to be File or
// something else, just be wary of the class's hashCode() semantics
private Map<String, ReadWriteLock> lockMap = new HashMap<String, ReadWriteLock>();

// lock to protect our registry - helps to prevent multiple threads
// from instantiating a lock with the same key
private Lock registryLock = new ReentrantLock();

// allow callers to specify the lock type they require
public enum LockType {
    READ, WRITE
}

public void acquire(String fileName, LockType type) {

    // lazily instantiates locks on first use
    ReadWriteLock lock = retrieveLock(fileName);

    switch (type) {
    case READ:
        lock.readLock().lock();
        break;
    case WRITE:
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        break;
    default:
        // handle error scenario
        break;
    }

}

public void release(String fileName, LockType type) {

    ReadWriteLock lock = retrieveLock(fileName);

    switch (type) {

    case READ:
        lock.readLock().unlock();
        break;
    case WRITE:
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
        break;
    default:
        // handle error scenario
        break;
    }

}

private ReadWriteLock retrieveLock(String fileName) {

    ReadWriteLock newLock = null;

    try {

        registryLock.lock();

        newLock = lockMap.get(fileName);

        // create lock and add to map if it doesn't exist
        if (newLock == null) {
            newLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
            lockMap.put(fileName, newLock);
        }
    } finally {

        registryLock.unlock();
    }

    return newLock;
}

}
```

And here is a simple test scenario to show the LockRegistry in action:

```
public class LockTester implements Runnable {

private int id;
private String fileName;
private LockType type;

public LockTester(int id, String fileName, LockType type) {

    this.id = id;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Consumer" + id + " acquiring " + type + " for "
                + fileName);
        LockRegistry.INSTANCE.acquire(fileName, type);

        System.out.println("Consumer" + id + " holding " + type + " for "
                + fileName);

        // hold the lock for 2 seconds
        Thread.sleep(2000);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        LockRegistry.INSTANCE.release(fileName, type);

        System.out.println("Consumer" + id + " release " + type + " for "
                + fileName);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Thread> testThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

    testThreads.add(new Thread(new LockTester(1, "file1", LockType.READ)));
    testThreads.add(new Thread(new LockTester(2, "file1", LockType.READ)));
    testThreads.add(new Thread(new LockTester(3, "file1", LockType.WRITE)));
    testThreads.add(new Thread(new LockTester(4, "file1", LockType.WRITE)));
    testThreads.add(new Thread(new LockTester(5, "file2", LockType.WRITE)));
    testThreads.add(new Thread(new LockTester(6, "file3", LockType.WRITE)));
    testThreads.add(new Thread(new LockTester(7, "file4", LockType.WRITE)));

    for (Thread t : testThreads) {
        t.start();
    }

}

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! One follow-up question: Is there a reliable way to determine if any locks are held in a particular `ReadWriteLock` instance? That way, in the release() method, I could delete the `ReadWriteLock` if it is no longer in use, so that I don't gradually accumulate `ReadWriteLock`s as the program runs.

Comment: The short answer is not easily with this implementation. The way I protected the locks prevents double instantiation of a lock for a key, but it is entirely possible that a lock could be deleted while another thread has a reference to it.  (Assuming the check to see if it's safe to delete a key happens at the end of release().)

Comment: Long Answer: Unless you anticipate opening thousands of different files, the size of your HashMap will probably be pretty negligible. While it admittedly would be pretty cool to have the object clean up automatically, it probably won't have much impact on memory performance.  You could also hinder performance if your cleanup routine causes locks to constantly be deleted and recreated.