# Data inconsistency in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have created an application which reads & writes into a remote file. I have different files (`A.properties`, `B.properties`, `C.properties`) in different directories (`folder-1`, `folder-2`, `folder-3`). Each directory has the same filename with different data.

I have implemented concurrency in my application by using the `LockRegistry` provided by [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771092/java-synchronization-locking-across-multiple-files#24771796). The issue is that if a thread is accessing `A.properties` while another thread accesses `B.properties`, the `propertyMap` displayed to the end user will contain both  data from property files. How can I resolve this issue?

My code:

```
public class UDEManager
{
    private Map<String, String> propertyMap  = new TreeMap<>();
    HttpSession session = null;

    public UDEPropertyManager()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        super.init(config);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // Code for calling thread for read/write operations into remote
        // file and fill the propertyMap
    }
}

class WebAppProperty implements Runnable
{
    private WebApp webapp; // folder-1
    private String propertyFile; // A.properties
    private String keyValue; //messages-title=Messages
    private LockType mode;

    public String getPropertyFile()
    {
        return propertyFile;
    }

    public void setPropertyFile(String propertyFile)
    {
        this.propertyFile = propertyFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            LockRegistry.INSTANCE.acquire(propertyFile, mode);

            if (this.mode == LockType.WRITE) {
                writeToPropertyFile();
            } else if (this.mode == LockType.READ) {
                getProperty(this.webapp, this.propertyFile);
            }
        } catch (Exception ie) {
            sysoutAndLog("Thread is Interrupted");
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            LockRegistry.INSTANCE.release(propertyFile, mode);
        }
    }

    private boolean getProperty(WebApp webapp, String property)
    {
        try {
            // read from file and put it into Map instance variable
            // of calling class (UDEManager)
            propertyMap.put(key, value);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            sysoutAndLog("Error while reading property ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void writeToPropertyFile()
    {
        try {
            // Write data into remote file
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sysoutAndLog("exception while writing to file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do realise that a servlet and its fields are shared by all requests, right? You need to associate the map with the request or user session.

Comment: Thank you Mark , it worked by associated the  map with session

Comment: @AnsarSamad add it as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

You should associate the properties map with the user session or request